# Generic collection as a Java method argument

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to make this work in Java?

```
 public static void change(List<? extends Object> list, int pos1, int pos2) {
  Object obj = list.get(pos1);
  list.set(pos1, list.get(pos2));
  list.set(pos2, obj);
 }
```

The only way I've successfully avoided warnings and errors is this:

```
 public static <T> T change(List<T> list, int pos1, int pos2) {
  T obj = list.get(pos1);
  list.set(pos1, list.get(pos2));
  list.set(pos2, obj);
  return obj;
 }
```

but I don't like to be forced to return a value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a [generic method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

```
public static <T> void change( List<T> list, int position1, int position2) {
    T obj = list.get(position1);
    list.set(position1, list.get(position2));
    list.set(position2, obj);
}
```

Comment: @Helper Method I believe the set method wont work with a wildcard, as both type of the list and type of the object inserted would be unknown

Answer (score 8):

In `java.util.Collections`, there's already a [`swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29).

This is how it's implemented in [OpenJDK source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java&l=489):

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
   final List l = list;
   l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

Interestingly, it uses a raw `List` type to do the job. The code generates warnings at compile time, but presumably `@author` Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter think this is tolerable.

Comment: Thank you, I've marked @krosenvold answer as accepted, because it answer the question, but I'm going to use Collections#swap, because it is already implemented.

Comment: Interesting implementation... also strange that they marked the list as final.

Comment: @Helper Method - You should try to mark everything as final.  Less bugs that way.  If you do it "right" you will find that about 90-95% of your variables can be made final.  Checkstyle and/or PMD have a check to tell you when you have something that could be marked final but is not.

Comment: I always mark member variables final but never local variables. I just try to keep my methods very short :-).

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture helper:

```
public static void change(List<?> list, int pos1, int pos2) {
    changePrivate(list, pos1, pos2);
}

public static <T> void change(List<T> list, int pos1, int pos2) {
    T obj = list.get(pos1);
    list.set(pos1, list.get(pos2));
    list.set(pos2, obj);
}
```